# Motopress Appointment Booking Plugin Failure

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

I am seeking help with this issue and there are the tracebacks or error logs.   I am receiving a critical error on my wordpress website

WordPress version 6.4.3
Active theme: Lotus Spa (version 1.2.2)
Current plugin: Appointment Booking (version 1.18.0)
PHP version 7.4.33

## Error Details

> An error of type E_ERROR was caused in line 168 of the file /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-content/plugins/motopress-appointment/includes/entities/Service.php. Error message: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getPrice() on array in /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-content/plugins/motopress-appointment/includes/entities/Service.php:168
> Stack trace:
> #0 /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-content/plugins/motopress-appointment/includes/admin-pages/manage/ManageServicesPage.php(37): MotoPress\Appointment\Entities\Service->getPrice()
> #1 /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-content/plugins/motopress-appointment/includes/admin-pages/manage/ManagePostsPage.php(113): MotoPress\Appointment\AdminPages\Manage\ManageServicesPage->displayValue('price', Object(MotoPress\Appointment\Entities\Service))
> #2 /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(324): MotoPress\Appointment\AdminPages\Manage\ManagePostsPage->manageCustomColumn('price', 879)
> #3 /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-includes/class-wp-hook.php(348): WP_Hook->apply_filters('', Array)
> #4 /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-includes/plugin.php(517): WP_Hook->do_action(Array)
> #5 /home/penadpaw/public_html/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-ta

I have tried searching for the function that raises the exception but could find it